# sort tuples in dictionary based on time value

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary, tuples

I have a dictionary looking like this:

```
dict1 = {'key1': ['x1', [(time1,value1), (time3,value3), (time2,value2)]],
         'key2': ['x2', [(time6,value6), (time4,value4), (time5,value5)]],
          ...}
```

For each key in the dictionary, I wish to sort the tuples based on the time. Looking at the example above, assume that

```
time1 < time2 < time3
time4 < time5 < time6
```

The output I wish is then

```
dict1 = {'key1': ['x1', [(time1,value1), (time2,value2), (time3,value3)]],
         'key2': ['x2', [(time4,value4), (time5,value5), (time6,value6)]],
          ...}
```

The first value for each key 'x1', 'x2' .. etc are redundant and should (if anything) just be removed.

Can anyone help me with the issue of sorting the tuples in the dictionary based on the time value?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use a dict comprehension with `sorted`:

```
>>> {k: [v[0]] + [sorted(v[1])] for k, v in dict1.items()}
{'key1': ['x1', [('time1', 'value1'), ('time2', 'value2'), ('time3', 'value3')]],
 'key2': ['x2', [('time4', 'value4'), ('time5', 'value5'), ('time6', 'value6')]]}
```

If you want to drop the `x` value, you can simplify this to this:

```
>>> {k: sorted(v[1]) for k, v in dict1.items()}
{'key1': [('time1', 'value1'), ('time2', 'value2'), ('time3', 'value3')],
 'key2': [('time4', 'value4'), ('time5', 'value5'), ('time6', 'value6')]}
```

I'm using strings instead of actual times and values here, but provided that those time objects compare properly, the code will work the same. Using `sorted`, the list of tuples will just be sorted by the first elements in those tuples (or the second in case the firsts are equal, etc).

Comment: I would assume `timeX` here refers to a `datetime` object. Would the solution still remain this simple?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Last time I checked, `datetime` can be compared and sorted just fine.

Comment: Cheers and thanks for being indulgent with my lack of python/coding skills